# Foreach not able to print the list elements

Tags: scala, foreach

I am working on spark project using Scala. I need to print each element of a list named 'c' along with a variable. I am using jdoodle right now to run this small code, I am getting "value foreach is not a member of Any" error and the error message points to the foreach in the print statement.

```
object Graph {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val line="1,2,3,4,5,6"
    val a = line.split(",")
    val b=Seq(a(0),a(0),a.drop(1).toList)
    val c=b(2)
    print(Seq((b(0),b(1)),(c.foreach{x=>print(s"($x,$b(1))")})))
  }
}
```

I want the result to be a sequence like this `[(1,1)(2,1)(3,1)(4,1)(5,1)(6,1)]`

Comment: in your example `b` is of type `Seq[io.Serializable]` which means `b(2)` is of `Serialisable`, not `List[Int]` as you would expect

Comment: you have to convert `c` to `Seq[Int]`. You can try `val c: immutable.Seq[Int] = b(2).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val data = "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(",")

//safe even if data is an empty Array()
val res = data.foldRight(Seq.empty[(String,String)]){ case (n,arr) =>
            (n,data.head) +: arr}

res.foreach(print)  //(1,1)(2,1)(3,1)(4,1)(5,1)(6,1)
```

(Suspiciously similar to [this mangled question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329099/4993128).)

Answer (score 0):

val line = "1,2,3,4,5,6"

val lineOut=line.split(",").toList.map(f => (f,line.head))